# How to write swagger API document for an API that has only 1 post endpoint?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a web server that exposes an interface to external application.

1. All methods are sent as POST requests(read as well as write/update).
2. There is only ONE endpoint URL for accessing all the 
   methods("/serve"). Inside the POST body there is a property called 
   "function" which defines the method name to be called.

How do I document the API of this server in swagger. An example doing similar stuff will be appreciated.

For example: Here is the sample body of a POST request:

endpoint URL: *https://test-web-service.example.com/serve*

type: *POST*

**Body**:

getCustomerById

```
{
      "function": "getCustomerById",
      "args": 
      ["CUST00001"]
}
```

getAllCustomers

```
{
      "function": "getAllCustomers",
      "args": 
      []
}
```

createCustomer

```
{
      "function": "createCustomer",
      "args": 
      ["CUST001","MAC","mailto:mac@example.com","PO Box 39100, Howick"]
}
```

updateCustomer

```
{
      "function": "updateCustomer",
      "args": 
      ["CUST001","MAC OWENS","mailto:mac@example.com","PO Box 39100, Howick"]
}
```

Thanks!